# Group Homomorphism Question from Completed Midterm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I just got my midterm back, and the professor isn't going to post solutions, so I was wondering if the MSE community can help me understand a multiple-part question. The problem was:

Let $\phi$ : $G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be a group homomorphism. Let $K$ = {$g | \phi(g) = e_2$}, where $e_2$ is the identity of $G_2$.

a) Show that $K$ is a group. (Proven and shown)

b) Define a relation $R$ on $X$ by $aRb$ if $f(a) = f(b)$. Show that $g_1Rg_2$ if and only if $g_1 ^{-1}g_2 \in K$.

c) Show that if $K$ = {$e_1$}, then $\phi$ is injective.

I understood part a) and was able to prove it successfully, but could not do b) or c) at all. I was completely lost on b), and for c), I was unable to show that $\phi : G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is injective. Any help with me understanding b) and c) would be tremendously helpful. Thank you!

p.s. I don't know how to make those yellow block things for questions/problems, so if anyone could help me edit that in that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: In question b), should we read $aRb\Leftrightarrow\phi(a)=\phi(b)$?

Comment: @C.Falcon I believe this is what the OP meant.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: This is all about the "kernel" of a homomorphism (hence the $K$). You can find the proofs of (b) and (c) in any introductory abstract algebra textbook, which might be why the professor is not posting solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember these two relationships with homomorphisms:
$$\phi(a) \cdot_{G_2} f(b)=f(a \cdot_{G_1} b)$$
$$\phi(a^{-1})=\phi(a)^{-1}$$

Now, let's do part b:
$$g_1 R g_2 \iff \phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2)$$
We have to get $e$ somewhere in here and since the expression we're trying to prove has an inverse on the left side, the most natural way to get $e$ is by multiplying both sides by the inverse of the left side of the equation:
$$g_1 R g_2 \iff e_{G_2}=\phi(g_1)^{-1}\cdot_{G_2}\phi(g_2)$$
Use the second equation at the top:
$$g_1 R g_2 \iff e_{G_2}=\phi(g_1^{-1})\cdot_{G_2}\phi(g_2)$$
Use the first equation at the top:
$$g_1 R g_2 \iff e_{G_2}=\phi(g_1^{-1}\cdot_{G_1}g_2)$$

For part c, look [at the second part of this proof](http://planetmath.org/agrouphomomorphismisinjectiveiffthekernelistrivial). Notice how it uses $f(g_1)=f(g_2) \iff g_1^{-1}\cdot g_2 \in K$, which is very similar to the statement proven in part b.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For b) Observe
\begin{align}
\phi(g_1) = \phi(g_2)  \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \phi(g_1)^{-1}\phi(g_2) = e_2 \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow  \ \ \ \phi(g_1^{-1}g_2) = e_2.
\end{align}

For c). Use b) and the definition of injective. Note what it means if $\phi(g_1^{-1}g_2) = e_2$ when $K=\{e_1\}$.